# Nuxt: how to explicitly name JS chunks?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `Nuxt` in static site generation mode. One requirement in my project is to deploy only certain routes, each with their respective assets.

But `Nuxt` gives chunks random names like `925446d.js`.

So I created a manual `router.js` and specified chunk names while importing my components:

```js
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '~/pages/about.vue').then(m => m.default || m)
```

But `Nuxt` doesn't take my chunk names into account and continues to give chunks random names, making it super difficult to single out which chunk goes with which route.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It looks like the correct way of writting things. Do you see it in the network tab ? Did you tried it in a basic component/page and see if it changes anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to identify chunks by name, Nuxt actually has a built-in mechanism do to that, using the property `filename` of the build config.

You can add the following in your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
{
  // ...
  build: { filenames: { chunk: () => '[name].js' } }
}
```

Some additional options do exist, [see documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#filenames).

Comment: You're the man! One thing, in the doc they warn "Be careful when using non-hashed based filenames in production as most browsers will cache the asset and not detect the changes on first load."
Any idea how to work around this issue with `Nuxt.js`?

Comment: @drake035 You probably still can add the hash after the name. `[name]_[contenthash].js` What matters here is that the filename is different so it's not cached by the browser.