# NuxtJS - How can I specify chunks file names instead if webpack hash?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to specify each chuck with a specific (fixed) name, I modified nuxt config as the below

```
  build: {
    transpile: ["vue-clamp", "resize-detector"],
    filenames: {
      chunk: () => '[name].js'
    }
  },
```

it works and I got

- f5c3f6a.js
- commons/app.js
- vendors/app.js
- app.js

All of them as generated as I need except the first one **(f5c3f6a)**, How can I specify this too ? please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuxt: how to explicitly name JS chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444681/nuxt-how-to-explicitly-name-js-chunks)

Comment: @kissu I think he added the same code as the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

I could be late to the party but had the same issue and I've fixed it by adding *app* property to *filenames*.

```
filenames: {
  ...
  app: () => '[name].js
}
```